# gRPC interface design advice - correct style for handling creates and updates

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

We are building a new platform with gRPC providing a messaging layer, which will ultimately expose the full set of functionality our API is expected to support.

We're trying to determine the best patterns for naming our interfaces, to avoid duplicate message types, having to onerously handle edge cases and

A simple example of what we're doing involves creating, updating and retrieving users. Here's an example of how our service might look today:

```
service Users {
  rpc GetUser(UserRequest) returns (core.user.User) {}
  rpc ListUsers(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (ListUsersResponse) {}
  rpc CreateUser(core.user.User) returns (core.user.User) {}
  rpc UpdateUser(core.user.User) returns (core.user.User) {}
}

message UserRequest {
  string id = 1;
}

message ListUsersResponse{
  repeated core.user.User users = 1;
}
```

GetUser is pretty straightforward - it takes in a simple UserRequest message of an ID, and returns a User (from our core package - many services in the app will take a User message as an input, so we're putting it in a shared location).

My question specifically refers to the Create/Update Users calls, as it's unclear what the optimal solution is. The two functions differ slightly, mostly in that in one case we'll have a user already, and thus an ID, and in the other we're creating a new user. In the Create case, we probably only have a subset of available fields that might exist on User - but we ideally would only have to maintain this list in one place as it could potentially get fairly large.  We could either:

- For each call, define a custom request/response message, and embed any common messages within. This would look something like the code below. My concern is, we'd end up essentially having a message type per call, which from a maintainability perspective could end up very onerous.

Code

```
message CreateUserRequest{ 
  core.User user = 1;
}
message UpdateUserRequest{
  int32 id = 1;
  core.User user = 2;
}
```

- We could expect/send the common message types, and rely on comments or other feedback mechanisms to encourage consumers to pass the correct values (what my original implementation demonstrated). My concern with this approach is, we'd end up having to add a lot of validation to ensure the fields they did provide are "correct".

I'm struggling to find many examples online of how other people have handled these sorts of issues. The example I've provided is fairly simple, but you can imagine throughout our project we'll have similar problems. What I'd love to see is a an example of a fairly complex gRPC interface someone has done in practice, or just feedback from someone who has used it extensively, to see what patterns around interface design they felt worked best.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [Google's networked API Design Guide](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/). Look at the [Naming Conventions](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/naming_convention). Especially the Method Names section on that page. You will see examples very similar to what you are trying to do, which happens to be very common.

For more concrete example, look at how [`etcd`](http://github.com/coreos/etcd) has written their [API here](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/etcdserver/etcdserverpb/rpc.proto). Similar to your `CreateUserRequest` and `UpdateUserRequest` `etcd` has [`MemberAddRequest`](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/etcdserver/etcdserverpb/rpc.proto#L790) and [`MemberUpdateRequest`](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/etcdserver/etcdserverpb/rpc.proto#L814).

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at UBER’s online design doc that provides justification for separate response implementations and gives detailed versioning and naming conventions